# Getting special characters with gettext

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, translation, gettext

I am using gettext to translate my site. In norwegian I need to use the charaters æøå, but they show up blank. I have set the `$encoding = 'iso-8859-1';`from [wikipedia](http://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) it says that æøå should be available, but as I said they show up blank. In poedit settings and my po/mo file I have set encoding to iso-8859-1.

ps. I want to support all langauges in the future so I would like to use the "best" encoding with the most characters so I don't need to change my code in the future to support new languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your last comment, you could switch to using UTF-8.  That will solve both of your problems...

Comment: Actually, 8859 should work, perhaps you don't have the Norweigian locale installed or configured on your system?

Comment: windows 7 for development and Windows Server 2003 for hosting

Comment: Look under "Example #2 setlocale() Examples for Windows" @ http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

It also refers to the locales @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/vclib/html/_crt_language_strings.asp